# WPF Draw UserControl based on the Class of the bound object

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, types, user-controls

im working on a menu which can display items.

Therefor i have a UserControl 'MenuItem' which displays an entity of the type 'MenuItemEntity'.
Cause there are submenus which are displayed in a different way there is another UserControl 'MenuItemGroup' which are bound to an entity of type 'MenuItemGroupEntity' containing different MenuItemEntities.

Now i have the following Problem:
The 'menu' should be bound to an entity of the type 'MenuEntity'.
Inside this i want to have an ObservableCollection which contains MenuItemEntity's AND MenuItemGroupEntity which are displayed in an StackPanel using an ItemsControl.
But i dont know if there is any way to analyze the actual element in the bound collection to draw either an MenuItem or an MenuItemGroup. Something like a switch maybe?

Normaly i would bind the items of the ObservableCollection in the 'MenuEntity' like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItemAndGroupCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <!-- IS THERE ANY WAY TO SWITCH BASED ON THE CLASS TYPE? -->
            <local:MenuItemGroup DataContext="{Binding}" />
            <local:MenuItem DataContext="{Binding}" />
            <!-- IS THERE ANY WAY TO SWITCH BASED ON THE CLASS TYPE? -->

        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I hope someone can help me out of this =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use "implicit" `DataTemplate`s, like this:

```
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyClass1}">
           <local:MyUserControl1/>
      </DataTemplate>

      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyClass2}">
           <local:MyUserControl2/>
      </DataTemplate>

      <!-- and so on... -->
  </Window.Resources>

  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItemAndGroupCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <!-- Do NOT specify an ItemTemplate here -->
  </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thats what i looked for. Thank you verry much. That was much easier than i thought.